# One button or two for sign up and log in?

Tags: buttons, hyperlinks

What do you think? Should sign up and log in links be split into two buttons or is it OK to have them in one?

N.B.: sign up form and log in form are on the same page.

Thx,
Alex

Comment: Do you have any reason to why you want to combine the actions, or is it simply a question on whether it would be accepted or not? If there's no apparent reason for combining them, screen real estate etc, then I would suggest sticking to the norm and provide both actions in separate buttons, this is what most users will expect.

Comment: In fact, we have been using a single button for one of our website for a long time now. It strikes me this morning... we could separate the two actions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[UxMovement](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-sign-up-and-sign-in-should-never-go-together/) made a pretty interesting note about the subject - don't forget to also read the comments.

To summarize, it doesn't truly matter if you've got one or two buttons, the important fact is that the user can easily distinct both, especially through their labels: *sign up* and *sign in* are too similar, and even if they are two buttons far away from each other, users will mix them up.

That said, I'd stick to the standard and provide **two buttons, as there are two actions**. A new user won't click on a *log in* button, and a known user won't click on a *sign up* button either.

Comment: Interesting reading :) Thx. What do you think of this "all-in one" button? https://www.box.com/

Comment: Seems nice to me, clearly understandable. It was also suggest in another article of UxMovement: http://uxmovement.com/navigation/innovative-navigation-techniques-to-save-you-header-space/ (check section *Unified Login/Sign Up Button*)

Comment: Good knowledge here. Thx. So here, we should focus on: text and, if possible, separating in a way the button in two or make two buttons.

Comment: I read the question as a single button with a single event handler, e.g. http://www.donotpay.co.uk/signup.php, and not 2 buttons visually unified as in the UxMovement article. Thoughts ?